# Create custom Icon component with different width & height in react ant design

Tags: reactjs, icons, antd

i want to create Custom Component Icon with width:100px & height:50px. I cannot have empty spaces, it should be in a rectangular shape not in square. is it Possible? fontSize && size create square icons.

Comment: explain more please

Comment: @FatemehQasemkhani i want to create an Icon having SVG component with width=100px & height = 50px.